# phpunit broken after upgrade to v3.5.3

Tags: macos, phpunit

I just upgraded phpunit via the PEAR package installer and this is the error that i'm getting:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addFileToFilter() in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 48

Where should I start in troubleshooting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your path to phpunit set right?

Comment: yes it is. which pear & which phpunit commands return the correct values. the weird thing is that the file exists where it's supposed to be. I also made sure my bash_profile is clean and it only contains the correct include path

Answer (score 0):

it was pure noobness that caused this problem. adding ".:" on the include_path on my php.ini file fixed the problem.

old:
include_path = ”/usr/local/PEAR:/php/includes”;

new:
include_path = ”.:/usr/local/PEAR:/php/includes”;

Thanks for the tip sanders, my phpunit path was set right, turns out my PEAR path wasn't.